# Using the `where` command through PHP

Tags: php, command-line, xampp, environment-variables, shell-exec

I am trying to get the path to certain exe's using the `where` command in the command prompt on windows.
Here is what i did in command prompt.

```
where g++
where java
where javac
where python
```

All of these are giving the correct output of the path in the console window which indicated that I have set the environment variables correctly.

But now When i try to run the commands using the `shell_exec()` function in `PHP`, only the call to `where java` and `where python` gives the correct output. I was even able to successfully execute a respective test file using these commands through PHP.

But strangely, `where g++` and `where javac` give this error in the browser when run through `PHP`:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Also if I get the outputs of these two commands on the console and then copy that into my script to compile a c++ or java file, it works perfect. But the `where` command returns the above `INFO` when run through the PHP script.

I am running the server on localhost using XAMPP. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: user permision issue, the user the script is running under does not have the same permissions, as you.

Comment: @Dagon how do I fix that? and why isn't it affecting the other 2 commands?